# Setting polar coordinates for coordinate system in TikZ via macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

### The problem

I would like to do something equivalent to the following:

```
\def\setX{{(0:1cm)}}
\tikzset{x=\setX}
```

"Debuggable" code (it doesn't run, because I put it the way I want it to be. the `\setX` inside `\tikzset` makes it not compile):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\setX{(0:1cm)}
    \tikzset{
      x={\setX},y={(50:0.7cm)},z={(90:1cm)}
    }
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,-1,0) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Motivation

After a few hours down the rabbit hole *not* figuring out how one would [Switch axes in 3d tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427397/switching-axes-in-3d-tikzpicture), I got curious of why this doesn't work. It's undoubtedly do to some `pgfkeys` magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about expanding the key value. Write `x/.expand once=\setX` for the key. It has to see explicitly the contents otherwise it complains about it.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\setX{(0:1cm)}
    \tikzset{
      x/.expand once=\setX,y={(50:0.7cm)},z={(90:1cm)}
    }
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,-1,0) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]