# "Switching" axes in 3d tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

## Overview

So say I want an arc between the `x` and `z` axis in the same way the following creates an arc between the `x` and `y` axis (MVCE):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      x={(0:1cm)},y={(50:0.7cm)},z={(90:1cm)}
    }
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,1,0) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};
    \draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### [image: Arc between x and y axis]

One solution to this exact problem is to do scope and tell `arc` that the `y`-axis is the `z`-axis.

```
    \begin{scope}
      \tikzset{y=(90:1cm)}
      \draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);
    \end{scope}
```

## The problem

However, I need this more generic since I don't necessarily know how the y-axis is defined, so I'm looking for a way to do, essentially this:

```
    \begin{scope}
      \switchYZAxes
      \draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);
    \end{scope}
```

or

```
    \begin{scope}
      \tikzset{y=\theZAxis}
      \draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);
    \end{scope}
```

The latter is problematic because it seems like I can't send polar coordinates to the `\tikszet` via a macro (which is the background for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427395/setting-polar-coordinates-for-coordinate-system-in-tikz-via-macro) question).

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\usetikzlibrary{3d}` you can use:

```
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0, blue, thick]
    \draw (0:0.3) arc (0:90:0.3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0, red, thick]
    \draw (0:0.3) arc (0:90:0.3);
\end{scope}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      x={(0:1cm)},y={(50:0.7cm)},z={(90:1cm)}
    }
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,1,0) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};

    %\draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0, blue, thick]
        \draw (0:0.3) arc (0:90:0.3);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0, red, thick]
        \draw (0:0.3) arc (0:90:0.3);
    \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    x={(0:1cm)},y={(50:0.7cm)},z={(90:1cm)}
  }

  \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,1,0) node[right]{$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};
  \draw (0,0,0) ++(0:.3) arc (0:90:.3);

  \def\rad{0.3}
  \coordinate (A) at (\rad, 0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0, 0, \rad);
  \draw[red] (A) edge[in = 0, out = 90] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend tikz-3dplot for that. You only need to draw the arcs in rotated planes. (The first scope is not necessary here, but I put it in case you want to extend the code.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,font=\sffamily]
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (1,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,1,0) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (0,0,1) node[right]{$z$};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[red] (0.3,0,0) arc (0:90:0.3);
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{90}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[blue] (0.3,0,0) arc (0:90:0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]